# How to remove ContentType requirement from NServiceKit request

Tags: servicestack, content-type

I am trying to make a RESTful web service using NServiceKit version 1.0.43. I want this to work without an outside service that is not including a ContentType in their header request. My web service is rejecting the calls with a "406 Unaccepted Content Type" although I have not set a default content type. How do I allow calls to this service without defining a ContentType?

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar with a RequestFilterAttribute in ServiceStack 4.x.  It may need some tweaking to work on NServiceKit's fork, but this gives you the general idea.  If a Content-type header is not sent in, it defaults it to JSON:

```
public class ContentTypeFixFilter : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        if (!req.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("content-type", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            req.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Json;
        }
    }
}
```

}